# big files upload twice on dropzone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone to handle uploads in a rails app. It works just fine with small files, but unfortunately, when it comes to files > 300MB, things go sour: The upload animation freezes (nevers reaches its 'complete' state), user must reload the page, only to see that his file uploaded twice.

```
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#resources-dropzone", {
   url: "<%= upload_resources_path %>",
   maxFilesize: 1000
});

  myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
   location.reload();
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.order-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').click();
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour ?